# Cant update a record in a database

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm making a Homework/Revision program for my coursework. I'm following this tutorial http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets12p9.html on how to make a database but theres something wrong with the my update button (btnUpdate)

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    txtFirstName.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(1) = txtFirstName.Text
    txtSurname.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(2) = txtSurname.Text
    txtUsername.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(3) = txtUsername.Text
    txtPassword.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(4) = txtPassword.Text
    txtClass.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(5) = txtClass.Text
    txtAdmin.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(6) = txtAdmin.Text
    txtHWP.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(7) = txtHWP.Text

    MessageBox.Show("Data updated")
End Sub
```

[image: If I change whatevers in this textbox and then click update]
[image: This happens, everything changes to TRUE apart from the textbox that I've changed]

```
Public Class AdminEditUsers 'this is the whole code

Dim MaxRows As Integer

Dim inc As Integer
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection 'THE CONNECTION OBJECT 

Dim dbProvider As String 'HOLDS THE PROVIDER 
Dim dbSource As String 'HOLDS THE DATA SOURCE 
Dim MyDocumentsFolder As String 'HOLDS THEDOCUMENTS FOLDER 
Dim TheDatabase As String 'HOLDS THE DATABASE NAME 
Dim FullDatabasePath As String 'HOLDS THE DATABASE PATH 

Dim ds As New DataSet 'HOLDS A DataSet OBJECT 
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter 'HOLDS A DataAdapter OBJECT 
Dim sql As String 'HOLDS A SQL STRING 

Private Sub AdminEditUsers_load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    'SET UP THE PROVIDER 
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

    'SET THE DATABASE AND WHERE THE DATABASE IS 
    TheDatabase = "\Visual Studio 2015/NEW_database.accdb"
    MyDocumentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    FullDatabasePath = MyDocumentsFolder & TheDatabase

    'SET THE DATA SOURCE 
    dbSource = "Data Source = " & FullDatabasePath

    'SET THE CONNECTION STRING 
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    'OPEN THE DATABASE 
    con.Open()

    'STORE THE SQL STRING 
    sql = "Select * FROM tbl_user"

    'PASS THE SQL STRING AND CONNECTION OBJECT TO THE DATA_ADAPTER 
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

    'Fill the dataset with records from the database table
    da.Fill(ds, "Users")

    'CLOSE THE DATABASE 
    con.Close()
    'Counts how many rows are in the table
    MaxRows = ds.Tables("Users").Rows.Count

    inc = -1

End Sub
Private Sub NavigateRecords()
    txtFirstName.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(1)
    txtSurname.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(2)
    txtUsername.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(3)
    txtPassword.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(4)
    txtClass.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(5)
    txtAdmin.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(6)
    txtHWP.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(7)

End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    If inc <> MaxRows - 1 Then
        inc = inc + 1
        NavigateRecords()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No More Rows")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    If inc > 0 Then
        inc = inc - 1
        NavigateRecords()

    ElseIf inc = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No Records Yet")

    ElseIf inc = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("First Record")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnLast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLast.Click
    If inc <> MaxRows - 1 Then
        inc = MaxRows - 1
        NavigateRecords()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnFirst_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFirst.Click
    If inc <> 0 Then
        inc = 0
        NavigateRecords()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click

End Sub

Private Sub btnCommit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCommit.Click

End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    txtFirstName.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(1) = txtFirstName.Text
    txtSurname.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(2) = txtSurname.Text
    txtUsername.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(3) = txtUsername.Text
    txtPassword.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(4) = txtPassword.Text
    txtClass.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(5) = txtClass.Text
    txtAdmin.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(6) = txtAdmin.Text
    txtHWP.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(7) = txtHWP.Text

    MessageBox.Show("Data updated")
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: `txtFirstName.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(1) = txtFirstName.Text` is assigning the expression `(ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(1) = txtFirstName.Text)` to the textbox.  Hence all the True/False displays

Comment: You'll need a SQL Statement. It appears that you need to do a little more research here... Try searching for "Update Microsoft Access SQL Database".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where are you actually updating the database?

Read *one more paragraph* in that tutorial:

> Close down your programme, then run it again. Click the Next Record button to move to the first record. It will still be "John Smith". The data you updated has been lost! So here, again, is why:
>
> **"Changes are made to the DataSet, and NOT to the Database"**

The tutorial shows you how to persist those changes to the database:

```
da.Update(ds, "AddressBook")
```

---

**Edit:** It would also appear that you're making a mistake on lines like this:

```
txtFirstName.Text = ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(1) = txtFirstName.Text
```

This may behave differently in different languages.  In C# for example, I think that the result of an assignment is the value being assigned, so something like this might work.  But in VB there are semantic contextual differences when using the same operator.  The assignment operator (`=`) is *also* the comparison operator, depending on the context.

So I suspect that this line of code is *comparing* the latter two items, and *assigning* the result of the comparison (`True` or `False`) to the first item.

Stick with what the tutorial is showing you, just assign the value to the data:

```
ds.Tables("Users").Rows(inc).Item(1) = txtFirstName.Text
```

There's no need to also try to assign the value back to the text box where you *got* the value, since logically that value is already there.

Comment: I was going to move onto that bit but it says that  > **"Run your programme, and click the Next Record button to move to the first record. "John" should be displayed in your first textbox, and "Smith" in the second textbox. Click inside the textboxes and change "John" to "Joan" and "Smith" to "Smithy". (Without the quotes). Now click your Update Record button. Move to the next record by clicking your Next Record button, and then move back to the first record. You should see that the first record is now "Joan Smithy"."** Mine just changes to True or false. I was going to move onto the next part

Comment: @justdavid98: I've updated the answer.  Essentially you're assigning the *comparison* between two values, rather than assigning the value itself.